# Custom hostname instead ISP's

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, hostname, reverse-dns

I have setup a Centos 5.5 server and a domain name (say mydomain.com) pointing to it (using bind9) with custom nameservers (like ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com). Everything works fine but there is something more I would like to have and don't know if it is possible.

Is it possible to have the returned host to be mydomain.com (PHP gethostbyaddr()), not host-static-x-y-a-b.myisp-provider.com? And how do I implement it if it's possible?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218532/what-is-reverse-dns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ownership to reverse that IP or IP block. Chances are if this is a home provider they will not allow that to happen.

If you are at a datacenter they might give you the rights or you will have to let them know what you want it reversed to and they will do it for you.

Comment: They will do it for you / Or you through an API unless you have one more more C networks (256 addresses these days, /24). Reverse mapping assignment in DNS always works in /24, so smaller networks can not be delegated.

Comment: @TomTom http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2317 outlines a method for delegating blocks smaller than /24.