# How do I change the name of my resolve host?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, host, resolve

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is reverse DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218532/what-is-reverse-dns)

Traceroute an IP and the last entry gives me the host the IP resolved to.  How do I change that?

Comment: Is it LAN or WAN IP? Do you have control of?

Comment: Simple, just traceroute a different IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the PTR record for that IP. If this is an RFC1918 IP block or is a net block allocated or SWIPed to you, then you can do this yourself. If not, then you'll need to contact your ISP or whomever owns that netblock.

Comment: I just learned this after posting the question.  I have some servers with SoftLayer.com and I see they have an option to update my RDNS.  I looked it up and that's exactly it!   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You change the result of the reverse lookup by changing the `PTR` record in the reverse lookup zone - the owner of the IP range controls where that record's delegated to.

If you have access to the `in-addr.arpa` zone for that IP range, then change it there.  If you don't, ask your ISP.