# Emails sent from my server are being flagged by SpamAssassin with the -1.274 RDNS_NONE

Tags: email, iredmail

I'm experiencing an issue with email delivery where SpamAssassin is flagging my emails with the RDNS_NONE result. I suspect it's due to a mismatch between my Reverse DNS (rDNS) and HELO settings, but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve it. I would appreciate any guidance or solutions.

Details:

Issue: Emails sent from my server are being flagged by SpamAssassin with the -1.274 RDNS_NONE result, indicating a problem with the rDNS setup.
Current Configuration:
HELO identity is set to mail.domain
rDNS for the server's IP address is also set to mail.domain.ip.in-addr.arpa
Observations:

Here are the tested values for this check:
IP: 50.76.70.61
HELO: mail.fullstackprogrammer.net
rDNS: mail.fullstackprogrammer.net.70.76.50.in-addr.arpa

Comment: Could you share the actual hostname? DNS related problems are hard to diagnose with incomplete details, and `mail.domain.ip.in-addr.arpa` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Have you created closed loop of `PTR` and `A` DNS records?  `PTR` record alone is usually ignored as it can be easily set to anything.

Comment: @EsaJokinen added the correct ip and rdns so hopefully that helps

Comment: @AnFi I do not have a ptr record is that done with the isp? or through cloudflare?

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/dns/glossary/reverse-dns/ has the information you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is reverse DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218532/what-is-reverse-dns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a typical typo in a DNS record.

In DNS zone file shorthand any name record that isn't terminated with a trailing dot <kbd>.</kbd> is not a fully qualified domain name.

The name server will append $ORIGIN (typically the zone name) to complete the short name and generate a FQDN.

Somebody intended to set your reverse DNS record:

```
 61.70.76.50.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN  PTR mail.fullstackprogrammer.net.
```

or using typical shorthand:

```
 61   IN    PTR mail.fullstackprogrammer.net.
```

but actually did:

```
 61.70.76.50.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN  PTR mail.fullstackprogrammer.net
```

(note the missing trailing dot) which then gets completed to:

```
61.70.76.50.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN  PTR mail.fullstackprogrammer.net.70.76.50.in-addr.arpa.
```

Correct that typo and your HELO name `mail.fullstackprogrammer.net.` will match the reverse DNS (PTR) record correctly.

Comment: You were a bit faster this time as I was playing Wii Fit. :)