# Proper rDNS in a multidomain server using the same IP

Tags: reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a server with one IP 92.150.180.250. I have 60 accounts. The host name is 92-150-180-250.hosted-by-myserver.com and the rDNS is exactly the same.

All domain DNS records are following the structures:

name=mydomain.com / type=NS / record=ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com
For the email configuration: name=mail.mydomain.com / type=CNAME / record=mydomain.com
And, an A record for the IP.

Many emails from each account go to the spam folder. The IP has a bad reputation in some providers. I was advised to do the following:

*The PTR-Record (rDNS) of your IP address "92-150-180-250" contains the
reverse DNS hostname "92-150-180-250.hosted-by-myserver.com". This
looks like an end user system to everyone. We recommend you set the PTR record to a non-generic hostname (in one of your own domains) like 'mail.your-company.com'.*

What should the rDNS look like to affect all domains? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is reverse DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218532/what-is-reverse-dns)

Comment: Translation: "talk to the persons that are the registered administrators for the IP network addresses for what are most likely a consumer IP allocation ".

Comment: Hire an admin - you obviously are not competent to read simple english error messages and have NO idea what you do.

Comment: @TomTom: Please be nice. See https://serverfault.com/help/behavior.

Answer (score 1):

While Greg's answer is a little tongue-in-cheek, it's not outright wrong.

Since you are hosting multiple clients that all use the same outgoing IP address for email, there's not going to be a "right" rDNS. The point being made by the other admin is that your rDNS is very generic looking. You'll want to get the rDNS update to something that better describes your system, such as **web.yourdomain.com** if you're doing general hosting or **mail.yourdomain.com** if you're just hosting email. You also want to make sure you have FCrDNS, meaning **mail.yourdomain.com** resolves to **92.150.180.250** and **92.150.180.250** resolves (through rDNS) to **mail.yourdomain.com**.

Now I don't know whether your IP address is classified as a "home" or "non-business" IP (it's listed as part of 92.150.176.0/21), but I do see it's on the SpamHaus[1] PBL, so you probably have more problems than just rDNS.

With all that said, if you are new to email hosting, there are a ton of other things that you must consider to be successful (proper SPF, DKIM, DMARC, EHLO greeting, clean IP addresses, feedback loops, etc). There's way too much go to into for a simple question like this. Email hosting is not something you can just throw together and hope it works.

[1] https://check.spamhaus.org/

Comment: Thanks, it's more understandable the way you explained it.

Answer (score -1):

> What should the rDNS look like to affect all domains?

dontjunkmailmebro.mydomain.com